# Access arraylist from other class through foreach loop

Tags: java, foreach, entity

I'm trying to access my ArrayList from my other class, through a Foreach-loop. But this doesn't seems to work, for some reason. No error, just simply won't execute the Foreach loop.

Heres my code:

```
for(Entity entity : world.entitys) {
if(entity.isMouseDown()) {
    System.out.println("Touching Entity");
} else {
    System.out.println("Is not Touching Entity");
}
}
```

Arraylist from World Class:

```
public ArrayList<Entity> entitys = new ArrayList<Entity>();
```

World is my other class. entitys is my Arraylist. Entity is my class for my entitys in the Arraylist.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean, "it does not work"? Please explain what you expect the result to be and what you get (with some sample data)?

Comment: Dont you want to replace Entity there with whatever the type of your ArrayList is?

Comment: is there anything in the world.entitys?

Comment: Is `entities` declared `public`in `world`?

Comment: You might want to post your code that is compilable or everyone here is going to be left guessing.

Comment: note - mouseDown() is deprecated/wait maybe not in slick/lwjgl

Comment: Ankit, Foreach loop just won't execute. - Nickecarlo, Entity is my type - Dave G, yes there is - hd1, yes it is - nickecarlo shouldn't be nercessary

Comment: @Jimmt isMouseDown() is my own method i made inside the Entity class

Comment: So you put  debug on the for statement. Entitys is not empty at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not compiler or runtime error thrown only reason per your description is that the ArrayList is empty...

Learn to debug, it will help you resolve this kind of problems without asking for anyone's help..

Comment: I know how to Debug, thank you very much.. I found the issue, my ArrayList was not empty, but the reason it didn't work, was because i was adding objects to my Arraylist from another class. And my Arraylist wasn't static, so that's why it would always be 0. Anyway, thanks ;)

Comment: I should have elaborated more I suppose, what I meant was that at the time of the loop execution it must be empty.. :-)

Comment: Well actually, the ArrayList wasn't empty at all, the reason being, that it didn't work, was because i was adding objects to my arrayList from "Another class", and ofcourse, i forgot to set my Arraylist to Static, which apperantly is needed for this. But i thank you very much, for your kind response and answer, when i was in need!